# How do I write a java method to accept click?

Tags: java, class, selenium, methods, action

I am creating methods for Selenium testing.  How do I write methods that I can use click?

Example

`Class.Method(somethingVariable).click()`

I know how to make class and method but how do I make `.click()`

```
public class MyClass{

    public static void newMethod(String strName) {
        --------
    }
}
```

I want to do `MyClass.newMethod("something")**.click()**`or `MyClass.newMethod("something")**.attr("html")**`etc

Comment: `click()` method is already defined by `Selenium Clients`, we simply need to invoke the method on `WebElements`. Are you looking to reinvent the same wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what are you trying to do. What you can do is called `method chaining`. The problem is, you are trying to use `static` method which is not applicable for `method chaining`.

If you REALLY want to use `Class.staticMethod().click();` then you would have to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private WebElement element;

    private MyClass(WebElement element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public static MyClass newMethod(String str) {
        //do something and THEN pass WebElement you want to click.
        return new MyClass(element);
    }

    public void click() {
        element.click();
    }
}

//usage
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass.newMethod("myString").click();
}
```

There is probably a lot to explain, so please, ask me in comments because I don't know which parts you do or don't understand.

Comment: Thank you Rafal, this is pretty well explained.

Comment: @Knight Accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks! :)

Comment: One question "private WebElement element;" is throwing me an error. asking me if I want to create new class..

Comment: @Knight You probably did not import selenium jars and it cannot import it. That's why it's asking you to create a new class. Resolve your build path :)